# Free objects and representable functor

Tags: category-theory

For the sake of completeness let me first begin with some definitions. I will be assuming the definitions of a [coslice category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_category).

> **Definition 1.** Let $(\mathbf{A},\mathscr{U})$ be a concrete category over $\mathbf{X}$ and $X$ is an $\mathbf{X}$-object. A $\mathbf{X}$-morphism $u:X\to\mathscr{U}(A)$ is said to be *universal* iff $(X,u,A)$ is an $(X\downarrow\mathbf{X})$-initial object (where $(X\downarrow\mathbf{X})$ denotes the coslice category of $\mathbf{X}$ with respect to $X$.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $(\mathbf{A},\mathscr{U})$ be a concrete category over $\mathbf{X}$ and $X$ is an $\mathbf{X}$-object. An $\mathbf{A}$-object $A$ is said to be *free over $X$* if there exists a universal $\mathbf{X}$-morphism $u:X\to\mathscr{U}(A)$.

The problem with which I am stuck is the following,

> Let $(\mathbf{A},\mathscr{U})$ be concrete category over $\mathbf{Set}$. Let $\{x\}$ be a singleton set and $A$ be an $\mathbf{A}$-object. Then $A$ is free over $\{x\}$ iff $\mathscr{U}$ is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(A,-)$ (where $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf{A}}(A,-)$ is the covariant [$\operatorname{Hom}$-functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor)).

I have not found any way of constructing the required natural isomorphism yet. Can anyone help me?

Comment: My answer to [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3462890/limit-functor-isomorphic-to-global-sections-functor) is closely related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u:\{x\}\to U(A)$ be an $U$-universal morphism.
For every object $B$ in $\mathbf A$  we have to define a bijection $\zeta_B:U(B)\to\hom_{\mathbf A}(A,B)$.
For every $b\in U(B)$, $\zeta_B(b)$ is the only morphism $A\to B$ such that $U(\zeta_B(b))\circ u$ is the function $\{x\}\to U(B)$ such that $x\mapsto b$.

[image]

Comment: How to prove the converse? Just give me a hint.

Comment: Consider $\zeta_A^{-1}(1_A)\in U(A)$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.